# How to calculate how many loops is needed without looping?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, math

If I have a value A which is being incremented by 10% of its current value while being taken away by a fixed amount B, how can I calculate how many loops will be needed to reach 0 without actually looping?

So this is how I would find it by looping:

```
LoopsNeeded = 0
A = 100
B = 20
while A > 0:
   C = A * 0.1
   A = A + C
   A = A - B
   LoopsNeeded = LoopsNeeded + 1
print(LoopsNeeded)
```

**On the first loop:**

```
initial values
A = 100
B = 20
-------
A > 0 = True
C = A(100) * 0.1 = 10
A = A(100) + C(10) = 110
A = A(110) - B(20) = 90
LoopsNeeded = 1
-------
A is now 90 on the next round of the loop
```

This results in 8 loops needed in total, if I do this with really big numbers, this loop may take a long time, what is a shorter way of doing this?

Comment: Is B always 20% of A?

Comment: @christophperrins He said `B` is fixed (constant) so I don't think so.

Comment: Hm interestingly then it will either tend towards -infinite or infinite. @Yonlif Thanks, I thought the same

Comment: It doesn't tend to infinite? I ran the current code and I get 8 loops needed at the end @ christophperrins

Comment: @Casabias sorry for the confusion, It tends to (-)infinite until it hits 0.

If A was 100, and B was 9, it wouldn't stop increasing.
If A was 100, and B was 10, it wouldn't change.
If A was 100, and B was 11, it wouldn't stop decreasing (until it hits 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let *A*<sub>*i*</sub> be the value of `A` after iteration *i*, where *A*<sub>0</sub> is 100.

Let's create a recursive formula for *A*<sub>*i*</sub>:

> *A*<sub>*i*</sub> = *A*<sub>*i*−1</sub> · 1.1 − *B*

If we expand it out, we get:

> *A*<sub>*i*</sub> = (*A*<sub>*i*−2</sub> · 1.1 − *B*) · 1.1 − *B* = *A*<sub>*i*−2</sub> · 1.1<sup>2</sup> − *B* · 1.1 − *B*
>   *A*<sub>*i*</sub> = (*A*<sub>*i*−3</sub> · 1.1 − *B*) · 1.1<sup>2</sup> − *B* · 1.1 − *B* = *A*<sub>*i*−3</sub> · 1.1<sup>3</sup> − *B* · 1.1<sup>2</sup> − *B* · 1.1 − *B*
>   ...
>   *A*<sub>*i*</sub> = *A*<sub>0</sub> · 1.1<sup>*i*</sup> − *B* · (1.1<sup>0</sup> + 1.1<sup>1</sup> + ⋯ + 1.1<sup>*i*−1</sup>)

So:

> *A*<sub>*i*</sub> = 100 · 1.1<sup>*i*</sup> − 10 · *B* · (1.1<sup>*i*</sup> − 1)

Or in general:

> *A*<sub>*i*</sub> = *A*<sub>*0*</sub> · (1 + *p*)<sup>*i*</sup> − *B* · <sup>((1 + *p*)<sup>*i*</sup> - 1)</sup> / <sub>*p*</sub>

To find the iteration *i* after which `A == 0`, we can set *A*<sub>*i*</sub> = 0 and solve for *i*:

> 0 = *A*<sub>*i*</sub>
>   0 = 100 · 1.1<sup>*i*</sup> − 10 · *B* · (1.1<sup>*i*</sup> − 1)
>   1.1<sup>*i*</sup> = 10 · *B* · (1.1<sup>*i*</sup> − 1)
>   *i* = log<sub>1.1</sub> (<sup>10 · *B*</sup> / <sub>(10 · *B* − 100)</sub>)

Or in general:

> *i* = log<sub>p + 1</sub> (<sup>-*B*</sup> / <sub>(*p* · *A*<sub>*0*</sub> − *B*)</sub>)

For *B* = 20, this gives *i* = 7.2. We round up, and indeed get 8.

Time complexity is `O(1)`.

Comment: If you want me to elaborate on some line please ask. I did some shortcuts with   geometric sequence sum.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with maths, in terms of converting this into python code I would be looking at this line? i = log on base 1.1 of 10 * B * (1.1 ^ (i - 1) - 1), how can I run this statement if i hasn't been defined yet?

Comment: @Casabias I am very sorry, just some copying mistakes, please read this part again.

Comment: Great! I get 7.272540897341713 as expected (yet to try on other values/compare the speed) but I had to import the math library to use math.log, can this be done without logs? I.e native python without using any imports?

Comment: For values A = 500 and B = 200 and A is incremented by 5% each time what would change? I assume the log to 1.05? But I'm confused with the ((10 * B) / (10 * B - 100)) part since there are static values of 10 and 100 here, what would they be?

Comment: @Casabias There are methods to calculate log without the math lib but they are a bit complicated. I will edit the question so you can do it completely general.

Comment: Thanks, in this case p is equal to the % it is being incremented? i.e p = 0.1 = 10%, correct?

Comment: @Casabias Correct :), if you are satisfied with the answer I would appreciate if you will approve it.